# Cumulative Word Count using R

Tags: r, rvest

Is there a way to obtain a cumulative word count of a text? I have a text that I am trying to analyze and I want to find a cumulative count of the total words in the text as well as the cumulative count of certain words in the text.

Currently I have 3 separate data frames. The first contains all words in the text document, a "count" column which contains 1's all the way down, and a "total" column that gives a cumulative sum of the "count" column. The other two data frames are exactly the same except they only contain all occurrences of the specific words I am looking for in the text.

The goal is to make a plot that shows the relationship of the use of the two specific words throughout the entire text.

Any help is appreciated. Below is what I have so far.

```
URL <- 'http://shakespeare.mit.edu/romeo_juliet/full.html'
romeo <- htmlParse(URL)
txPath <- "//blockquote//a"
txValue <- xpathApply(romeo, txPath, xmlValue)
txValue <- strsplit(gsub('\\n','',txValue), split="  ")

words <- unlist(str_extract_all(txValue,'(\\w+)\'*(\\w+)'))
vWord <- tolower(words)
rCount <- unlist(str_extract_all(vWord,'(romeo)'))
lCount <- unlist(str_extract_all(vWord,'(love)'))

rDF <- as.data.frame(rCount) %>%
  mutate(count=1) %>%
  mutate(tot=cumsum(count))
lDF <- as.data.frame(lCount) %>%
  mutate(count=1) %>%
  mutate(tot=cumsum(count))
wordsDF <- as.data.frame(vWord) %>%
  mutate(count=1) %>%
  mutate(tot=cumsum(count))
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Sure, I edited my post to include my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This shows how to use `stringi` (faster and more flexible than built-in string ops) for the corpus slicing & dicing and one way to plot the comparison you're looking for:

```
library(xml2)
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(stringi)
library(ggplot2)

URL <- 'http://shakespeare.mit.edu/romeo_juliet/full.html'
wherefore <- read_html(URL)

txt <- stri_trim(html_text(html_nodes(wtxtherefore, "blockquote > a")))

corpus <- data_frame(word=stri_trans_tolower(unlist(stri_extract_all_words(txt))),
                     count=1)
corpus$word_number <- 1:nrow(corpus)

cumsum_corpus <- mutate(group_by(corpus, word), cumsum=cumsum(count))

gg <- ggplot(filter(cumsum_corpus, word %in% c("romeo", "juliet")),
             aes(x=word_number, y=cumsum))
gg <- gg + geom_line(aes(color=word), size=0.75)
gg <- gg + geom_point(aes(fill=word), shape=21, color="white", size=1.5)
gg <- gg + scale_x_continuous(limits=c(1, nrow(corpus)))
gg <- gg + theme_bw()
gg
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that is pretty much exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

It would help if you included your data and your desired output. But given my understanding, could you use your 'first' data.frame to do something such as (via `dplyr`):

My take on your 'first' data.frame:

```
df <- data.frame(word = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "a", "c", "d", "b", "a"),
                 count = rep(1,9))

library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(word) %>% mutate(cumsum= cumsum(count))
```

Output:

```
    word count cumsum
      (fctr) (dbl)  (dbl)
    1      a     1      1
    2      b     1      1
    3      c     1      1
    4      a     1      2
    5      a     1      3
    6      c     1      2
    7      d     1      1
    8      b     1      2
    9      a     1      4
```

And also, because I need to force myself to learn `data.table`, here's a solution using that:

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(df)[, cumsum:=cumsum(count), by=word]
```

Comment: Thanks I will have to try that. I also edited my post to include my code.